# How to calculate accuracy score of a random classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, evaluation

Say for example, a dataset contains 60% instances for "Yes" class and 30% instances for "NO" class. 
In this scenario, Precision, Recall for the random classifier are

Precision =60%

Recall =50%

Then, what will be the accuracy for random classifier in this scenario?

Answer (score 19):

Some caution is required here, since the very *definition* of a random classifier is somewhat ambiguous; this is best illustrated in cases of imbalanced data.

By definition, the accuracy of a binary classifier  is

```
acc = P(class=0) * P(prediction=0) + P(class=1) * P(prediction=1)
```

where `P` stands for probability.

Indeed, if we stick to the intuitive definition of a random binary classifier as giving

```
P(prediction=0) = P(prediction=1) = 0.5
```

then the accuracy computed by the above formula is always 0.5, irrespectively of the class distribution (i.e. the values of `P(class=0)` and `P(class=1)`).

However, in this definition, there is an *implicit assumption*, i.e. that our classes are *balanced*, each one consisting of 50% of our dataset.

This assumption (and the corresponding intuition) breaks down in cases of **class imbalance**: if we have a dataset where, say, 90% of samples are of class 0 (i.e. `P(class=0)=0.9`), then it doesn't make much sense to use the above definition of a random binary classifier; instead, we should use the percentages of the class distributions themselves as the probabilities of our random classifier, i.e.:

```
P(prediction=0) = P(class=0) = 0.9
P(prediction=1) = P(class=1) = 0.1
```

Now, plugging these values to the formula defining the accuracy, we get:

```
acc = P(class=0) * P(prediction=0) + P(class=1) * P(prediction=1)
    = (0.9 * 0.9) + (0.1 * 0.1)
    = 0.82
```

which is nowhere close to the naive value of 0.5...

As I already said, AFAIK there are no clear-cut definitions of a random classifier in the literature. [Sometimes](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/03/classification-models.html) the "naive" random classifier (always flip a *fair* coin) is referred to as a "random guess" classifier, while what I have described is referred to as a "weighted guess" one, but still this is far from being accepted as a standard...

The bottom line here is the following: since the main reason for using a random classifier is as a *baseline*, it makes sense to do so only in relatively *balanced* datasets. In your case of a 60-40 balance, the result turns out to be 0.52, which is admittedly not far from the naive one of 0.5; but for highly imbalanced datasets (e.g. 90-10), the usefulness itself of the random classifier as a baseline ceases to exist, since the correct baseline has become "*always predict the majority class*", which here would give an accuracy of 90%, in contrast to the random classifier accuracy of just 82% (let alone the 50% accuracy of the naive approach)...

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. It makes more sense.

Comment: The definition of the accuracy is not correct here. It should be conditional probability for prediction, or accuracy cannot add up to 1.0.
Although this complicates up the explanation, you should mention that taking random approach makes independent decision from outcome, thus can drop the conditional factor.

Answer (score 0):

As @desertnaut mentioned, if you're after a naïve benchmark for your model you're always better using "always predict the majority class" as your benchmark, achieving accuracy of %of_samples_in_majority_class (which is always better than either a random guess or a weighted guess).

In [Deepchecks](https://docs.deepchecks.com/en/stable/examples/guides/quickstart_in_5_minutes.html) (a package I maintain) we have a check that automatically compares the performance of your model to a simple model (either weighted random, majority class or simple decision tree).

```py
from deepchecks.checks import SimpleModelComparison
from deepchecks import Dataset
SimpleModelComparison().run(Dataset(train_df, label='target'), Dataset(test_df, label='target'), model)
```